# Error when running a script

Tags: wordpress, git, unix, ssh, capistrano

I have the following capistrano script (re-indent for simplicity):

```
sh -c 
    'git clone -q git@github.com:naorye/WebDevEasy-Wordpress.git /home1/webdevea/public_html/staging/shared/cached-copy &&
    cd /home1/webdevea/public_html/staging/shared/cached-copy &&
    git checkout -q -b deploy e508df390778be1d6ce4c4f7ceb71db149fa8f77 &&
    git submodule -q init &&
    git submodule -q sync &&
    export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\" \\< \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive) &&
    git submodule -q update --init $GIT_RECURSIVE;'
```

This code generated by WP-stack: https://github.com/markjaquith/WP-Stack
When running this on remote machine, I get an error:

```
-bash: "git: No such file or directory
```

When debugging (running lines one by one), I see that the line that makes the error is:

```
export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\" \\< \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive)
```

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how the script is generated but there seems to be some unnecessary escapes. I cleaned it and the following works for me:

```
export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! "`git --version`" \< "git version 1.6.5" ] && echo --recursive) &&
```